# Is asynchronous non-blocking event driven approach the only way to "asynchronous programming"?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, events, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm bit confused about the terminology here. Let a program consists of some tasks, conceptually distinct:

> In the asynchronous programming model tasks are interleaved with one another, but in a single thread of control. A single-threaded asynchronous system will always execute with interleaving, even on a multi-processor system. There is no actual parallelism.

Is the event-driven approach the only way to do "asynchronous programming"?

Comment: This smells like a discussion more than an actual question. What do you imagine would be an answer? One other approach? A list of them? (And for that, you'd still have to define "asynchronous programming". Why are threads not an approach to asynchronous programming?)

Comment: Also, I suggest you look at what Erlang does. Pretty much the entire point of the language is to implement an architecture for modelling concurrency, and this is done by having potentially independent tasks or actors exchange messages as the only means of sharing data. These are scheduled cooperatively on multiple threads. This might be seen as either different from the Node.js style which involves passing around explicit continuations; or it might be seen as kind of the same thing since you still have one task "tell" another when to continue. (High-level architectural concepts are ambiguous.)

Comment: So I suppose your question reads as asking us to compare a strawberry with a cucumber. Botanically they're both fruits (berries even), culinarily they're worlds apart. Hence it's not even clear by which criteria an approach would be different or not from the one you mention since you can always draw subtle parallels or find minor differences.

Comment: Where did you copy that quote from?  Since when did 'async programming model' mandate 'single thread of control'?  I may do with 'node.JS' blinkers on, but it does not in general.

Comment: @MartinJames here http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/f12/handouts/async.pdf

Comment: Okay, going by that diagram, that seems to cover "cooperative multitasking", which is a very broad category of concurrency approaches. And, well, can still encompass parallelism and lack of interleaving, like in Erlang's actor model. (Which is at the very least not competitive.) Also, the claim that "as the number of threads increases, your server may start
to experience performance problems" is a bit FUD-ish. See [The C10K Problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html), which implies it's not a cut-and-dry issue.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: there are other ways.

Long answer: it depends what technology you're using. For instance, JS doesn't provide any non-evented asynchrony methods (at least, that I'm aware of). However, in C and many other languages, you can use signals in user processes to do asynchronous programming.

The distinction between evented and non-evented async programming is that evented programming is a wrapper over the lower-level non-evented style that eases reasoning about what can happen in what context and helps to bound the stack depth.

1. **Easing reasoning**: Let's say you're writing a program that does some I/O and is sent a signal when the I/O completes. In your signal handler, you could immediately handle that I/O, but you have to be careful about what you do in the handler. For instance, if you need to take a lock, you have to know that the thread which was interrupted (the one whose stack you just commandeered) isn't holding the lock, otherwise you'll immediately cause a deadlock. Also, what happens if you grab the lock and then another I/O finishes? Also, what should happen if the thread which is interrupted by the signal is very high-priority and your handler causes it to wait for a long time? Basically the answer is: "Never do anything that requires synchronization in a signal handler." Evented programming achieves this by adding events to a queue in the signal handler and then exiting, allowing threads to dequeue and handle the event at a later time.
2. **Bounding the stack depth**: As I already alluded to, multiple signal handlers can run at the same time on the same stack (the later ones interrupting the earlier ones). If you're receiving signals frequently, you could end up in the unfortunate position of a stack overflow. For this reason, it's a very good idea to keep signal handlers short and sweet. Evented programming achieves this by doing only a single, very simple operation: adding a task to a queue.

The downside to evented programming is that it can be slower if it's used naively. For instance, let's say your tasks are very large, but every once in a while the user presses a button and a letter is supposed to appear on the screen. If you handle the button press in the signal handler, it can appear on the screen right away. If you add it to a queue, it could be a while before the button press event actually gets handled. You can give events priorities in some evented programming frameworks to deal with this, but the best practice is to keep all your evented tasks very short and run any long-running stuff in a separate thread pool. This (among other reasons) is why evented frameworks almost always rely on async I/O.

Comment: Also, not quite related to your question, but a link you might find interesting about different types of asynchronous I/O: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-async/